How to create a List from an Array<any IRow>
I try to create a List from an array containing types which are conforming to a protocol.
I can map and downcast the types in .onAppear, but I can’t use the array as a source for the List and do the downcast to create text views.
Compiler message is

'Type 'any IRow' cannot conform to ‘Identifiable’’

If I use id like this

List(item.rows, id: .self)

the compiler message is about

‘cannot conform to ‘Hashable’

protocol IRow: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id: UUID { get }
    var rowType: String { get }
}

struct TextItemRow: IRow {
    let id = UUID()
    let rowType = "text"
    
    var text: String = ""
}

struct HeadlineItemRow: IRow {
    let id = UUID()
    let rowType = "headline"
    
    var text: String = ""
}

struct Item: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var rows: [any IRow] = [HeadlineItemRow(text: "H_mock"), TextItemRow(text: "T_mock")]
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let item = Item()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(item.rows) { row in
                
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            var _ = item.rows.map() {
                if let r = $0 as? HeadlineItemRow {
                    print("\(r.id.uuidString) : \(r.text)")
                } else if let r = $0 as? TextItemRow {
                    print("\(r.id.uuidString) : \(r.text)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


Hey, this answer could be really helpful. Take a look: https://forums.swift.org/t/how-to-conform-protocol-to-identifiable/66189

Thanks for taking the time. And yes it does answer my question perfectly well. Only the id part was missing.

One question if I may. What is exactly the difference between my solution ‘id: .self and ‘id: .id’.

Good question, I generally avoid conforming to Identifiable unless a meaningful id can be provided, opting for id: .self in SwiftUI for clarity. Using self as id directly can lead to performance issues, such as a linear hash method and the inability to animate changes.

Try
List(item.rows, id: \.id) { row in 
   Text(row.rowType)
}

works for me.
